# How to fix the directory that shows me a "forbidden" message when i open it in the browser?

Tags: php, apache, ftp, apache2, filezilla

I was using a hosting to run my site, lately it has been working fine but today i opened the site in the browser at "http://www.arquisanjose.org/ver2" and shows me the following message:

[image]

i´ll appreciate some of your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have the Options directive configured correctly for that folder.  To enable for just that folder, you can drop an .htaccess with the following in that folder:

> Options +Indexes

Answer (score 1):

check your `access permissions` on the `directory`, they should be something like this:

- Numerical:  0755
- Flags:  DRWXR-XR-X

Edit: From your screenshot, it looks like you've got some kind of authentication module (`mod_auth_passthrough`).. you might check to make sure it's configured properly.

Comment: thanks but in the permissions value i get 00, the site was working ok i dont know what is happening to it...

Comment: Try changing the permissions back.. your `FTP` client should be able to. If it doesn't, or if you get an error, you should be able to do it via `SSH` (assuming your provider has it).

Comment: You may want to check your `log files`, see if you can figure out what changed it in the first place.